# Gulp-compile-handlebars for multiple html pages?

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js

As of now I just have two gulp tasks, ex `gulp.task('handlebars-index')`, `gulp.task('handlebars-about')`. Below is code from the docs, https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compile-handlebars

I am not sure how I can handle the task for two .handlebars files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('handlebars', function () {
    var templateData = {
        firstName: 'Kaanon'
    },
    options = {
        ignorePartials: true, //ignores the unknown footer2 partial in the handlebars template, defaults to false
        partials : {
            footer : '<footer>the end</footer>'
        },
        batch : ['./src/partials'],
        helpers : {
            capitals : function(str){
                return str.toUpperCase();
            }
        }
    }

    // here how do I add an index.html and say and about.html?
    return gulp.src('src/index.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

You can see with the above the task basically takes the index.handlebars then compiles it and creates an index.html file.

If I added an array of handlebar files how will the task know how to create the .html version?

```
    return gulp.src(['src/index.handlebars','src/about.handlebars'])
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(rename('about.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

The above won't work obviously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gulp-rename also takes a function where you can change only part of the path.

```
return gulp.src('src/*.handlebars')
    .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.extname = '.html';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename#usage

Comment: Okay, looks good thanks, sure beats having 3-4 gulp tasks lol. I should have payed more attention to the Gulp-rename plugin, I was scouring the gulp-compile-handlebars docs. Thanks man you rock!